# why is my intellij customized include file header "on/date" template is shifted to the right?

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated my `intellij` `include File Header` to look as following:

```
/**
 * @author ${USER}
 * on ${DATE}
 */
```

but when I create new file I get:

```
/**
 * @author jas
 *         on 31/03/15
 */
```

as you see the `on` is shifted to the right.  What did I do wrong on my template?

Comment: Does your include file header use spaces or a tab between `*` and `on ${DATE}` ?

Comment: to be sure I deleted the character between the `*` and the `on` and clicked on <kbd>space</kbd> i get the same behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go into `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `Java`, find the `JavaDoc` tab and disable `Enable JavaDoc Formatting`